# Assumptions on the Levene's test

Tags: levenes-test, variability

I'm trying to conduct the **Levene's test** for 10 non-normal samples to study an eventual heteroscedasticity. I was trying to justify my applying of this test, but I can't find it's clear assumptions. Can anyone tell me them?